# what's wrong ? An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: c#

```cs
    private void button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try 
        {
            if (isValid())
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO DataEntry Values(@vehicleid,@vehiclename,@exteriorcolor,@interiorcolor,@model,@vin_number,@plate_number,@location,@option_codes,@dateofentry,@note),con");

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vehicleid", txt_vehicleid.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vehiclename", txt_vehiclename.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@exteriorcolor", txt_exteriorcolor.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@interiorcolor", txt_interiorcolor.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@model", txt_model.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vin_number", txt_vinnumber.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@plate_number", txt_platenumber.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", txt_location.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@option_codes", txt_optioncode.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateofentry", txt_dat.Text = string.Empty);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@note", txt_note.Text);

                con.Open();

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                con.Close();

                LoadGrid();

                MessageBox.Show("Successfully registered", "Saved", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                cleardata();
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Usually the message of an exception gives additional information. Unfortunately you haven't told us that, or which line has thrown the exception...

Comment: Crystal ball says: "@dateofentry can't be null or empty"

Comment: Run SQL Server Management Studio and check log file under explorer management tab.

Comment: What's up with this: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateofentry", txt_dat.Text = string.Empty);`? What is that supposed to be doing? What it's actually doing is clearing the text in that `TextBox` and then assigning an empty `string` to the `Value` of that parameter. I doubt that's what you want. Why would you be using any `string`, let alone an empty one, where it appears that a `DateTime` would be expected?

Comment: Is txt_dat.Text a string or a DATE.  Dates cannot be null.  The variable name is "@dateofentry"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure that this is the specific issue or the only issue but this:

```cs
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO DataEntry Values(@vehicleid,@vehiclename,@exteriorcolor,@interiorcolor,@model,@vin_number,@plate_number,@location,@option_codes,@dateofentry,@note),con");
```

should definitely be this:

```cs
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO DataEntry Values(@vehicleid,@vehiclename,@exteriorcolor,@interiorcolor,@model,@vin_number,@plate_number,@location,@option_codes,@dateofentry,@note)", con);
```

Be sure to scroll right to see the difference.